# typescript tsconfig.json include exclude not working

Tags: typescript, glob, tsconfig

I have a web project

I have folders

```
src/app/shared/models
src/app/shared/services
src/app/shared/types
```

Each one of those is subfolder that have folders or files inside it, I want to exclude those folders, So i tried:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/app/shared/**/*"
  ]
```

and its not working, even `"src/app/shared/*"` not working, How I can do it?

My tsconfig.json now:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/app/shared/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first thing to consider, if you decide to use the “`exclude`” keyword to list files is that, in order to remove them from the compilation process, you will need also to exclude any other files, which by using either a triple-slash directive "`/// <reference path="..." />`" or an "`import`" statement refer to a file in your excluded list.

`tsconfig.json` turns a folder into a “project”. Without specifying any “`exclude`” or “`files`” entries, all files in the folder containing the `tsconfig.json` and all its sub-directories are included in your compilation.

`tsconfig.json` automatic inclusion does not embed module resolution. If the compiler identified a file as a target of a module import, it will be included in the compilation regardless if it was excluded in the previous steps.

> **The `include` and `exclude` properties take a list of glob-like file patterns. The supported glob wildcards are:**
>
> - `*` matches zero or more characters (excluding directory separators)
> - `?` matches any one character (excluding directory separators)
> - `**/` recursively matches any subdirectory
>
> When using the `files` property it takes a list of relative or absolute file paths.

Setting "`baseUrl`" informs the compiler where to find modules. All module imports with non-relative names are assumed to be relative to the baseUrl.

Files included using "`include`" can be filtered using the "`exclude`" property. However, if you include files explicitly using the "`files`" property they would be always included regardless of "`exclude`".

Comment: can you paste how would look a good config according to this explanation?

Comment: why ts does not throw error or at least give a warning when someone imports in the includes files, values from the exclude files?